# apply free shipping over $230 and discount over $100 on coupon code

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

1. Currently  I am offering free shipping over $130
2. Now I would like to give new offer. that was it **apply free shipping over $230  and discount 14% over  $100 on coupon code**

. But now problem is I don't want to give **1** offer to him who use **2** offer

Answer (score 0):

If there are no more promotions to be applied you can setup the rules like this:

1. Give the 2nd promotion higher priotity than the 1st one.
2. Change in `Actions` tab `Stop further rules processing` to *yes*.

Now whenever the 2nd rule with higher priority will be activated all other rules won't be applied.